# Не работает фильтрация spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Всем привет. Учусь использовать spring security.
Проблема в том, что вроде всё настроил, апи работает, но endpoints которые я настроил не работают. 
Всех пускает на все урлы, вне зависимости авторизован ли я или нет. Подозреваю что я где то что забыл добавить. 
мой web.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
>      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
> <display-name>star-network</display-name>
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
>     <param-value>
>         org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
>     </param-value>
>
> </context-param>
> <listener>
>     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
> </listener>
>
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
>         <param-value>
>             org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
>         </param-value>
>     </init-param>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>         <param-value>ru.starry_sky</param-value>
>     </init-param>
>     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
>
>
> <session-config>
>     <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
> </session-config> </web-app>
> ```

Мой класс который extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
package ru.starry_sky;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import ru.starry_sky.security.jwt.JwtConfigurer;
import ru.starry_sky.security.jwt.JwtTokenProvider;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    private final static String ADMIN_ENDPOINT = "/starry_sky/admin/**";

    private final static String USER_ENDPOINT = "/starry_sky/users/**";

    private final static String LOGIN_ENDPOINT = "/starry_sky/login/**";


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity.httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(LOGIN_ENDPOINT).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(ADMIN_ENDPOINT).hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(USER_ENDPOINT).hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }
}
```

Ссылка на проект https://github.com/SoaQa/social-web/tree/starry_sky

Answer (score 0):

Не зарегистрировал свой фильтр в контексте.

решил создав класс расширяющий AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.